# Host Spring Boot + Angular + MySQL Application on cPanel

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, deployment

I'm currently working on a management web application that uses Spring boot for the backend and angular for the frontend. I want to host this application specifically on BlueHost but I can't find any tutorial or explanation on how to properly do this.

I heard the best method to do this is to host the backend and the frontend separately but I'm not sure how to do that.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can host on the same system using different ports. When integrating the backend with the frontend you may encounter [CORS ERROR](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/angular-cors-guide-examples-and-how-to-enable-it/). To get out of the error, we can implement a proxy. In this [git repository](https://github.com/claubermartins/front-crud-angular) there is a proxy implementation to integrate backend & frontend in Angular with Springboot.